# Passing body message outside the scope in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

Till now, my experience told me that the body in message is always changed with any processing on it. So for now I always process data and finally the result always appear on the body where I can take it for further processing.

Currently I'm experiencing something strange - or, not strange, but something which I didn't use to.

I'm using following route

```
<route>
  <from uri="activemq:queue:add"/>
  <split>
    <simple>${body}</simple>
    <bean ref="pool" method="add(${body.getId},${body.getText})"/>
    <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="GOOD BODY ${body}"/>
  </split>
  <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="BAD BODY of type of argument of add method ${body}"/>
</route>
```

and I want at least access the result of add method as it is shown in GOOD BODY log, but finally the body later on is for some reason exchanged with the original type of argument of called method add.

I'm working here on split ArrayList, but anyway finally I need just one result for single entry. Also I need to add all objects on the list with add method, so I can not work on single entry only.

How can I pass the result of "internal" processing to pass it outside back to the originating calling route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the split, eg after `</split>` Camel uses by default the original message that was sent into the splitter.

If you want to use something else, then use the `aggregationStrategy` on the splitter to build the message you want, for example the last splitted message or something else.

See more details in the Camel documentation: http://camel.apache.org/splitter

Comment: I played a little bit with the `aggregationStrategy` and use `UseLatestAggregationStrategy` with some really simple `correlationExpression`, but finally I have to pass it to some queue/child - and I don't want to do this - I want to return aggregated part to the "caller" from the original route. Is there any trick which I can use to cover InOut pattern instead of passing it to new endpoint?